# git of my organizations repository renamed and now I can not sync to it

Tags: git, github

I have renamed a repository. This is a private repository belonging to an organization. I am no longer able to sync my commits with github windows client. I receive this error when I do.

The repository doesn't seem to exist anymore. You may not have access, or it may have been deleted or renamed.

Let's assume the following

**My name**
myname
**Organization name**
orgname
**old repository name**
oldrepos
**new repository name**
newrepos

I have tried all of the following as the remote

```
git@github:myname/oldrepos.git
git@github:myname/oldrepos.git
git@github:orgname/newrepos.git
git@github:orgname/newrepos.git
```

These apply to push and fetch.

**My ideas are**

Perhaps I need to renew or change the authentication, renew my password. If so, how?

Perhaps the remote is not one of the remotes I tried above.

If anyone knows how this can be fixed, or has some troubleshooting steps I can take, it would be much apprecitaed.

Comment: So the repo is hosted on github? What does the clone URL on the github page look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an myself answer that works. I have used the HTTPS clone URL on the repositories page as the remote.

```
https://github.com/orgname/newrepos.git
```

I still wonder if there's a more appropriate way to do this. I would think the git@github:syntax is preferable. This works however, for anyone who faces this issue.